# Styling similar to the popup that comes with required attribute of input tag

Tags: html, css

I am having a form on my website. I am using required for some fields which gives a popup when a field has no value on submission. I have a field named mobile number for which I have used javascript to check whether the number entered is valid or not. If the number is not valid I want to show a similar popup as shown by required with a custom message("mobile number invalid"). So how can I style it or is there any method available?

```
<form action="." method="post" onsubmit="return validat()">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control valid" name="conmobile" id="mobilenumber" type="tel" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your Mobile Number'" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Number" required>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Styling of these popups is browser dependant. Do you just want them to be consistent, or do you want to copy a specific style?

Comment: I want a one similar to that which comes with required attribute

Comment: can you show some of your code you tried so far, that will be easy to help you

Comment: Done in the question

Comment: "I want a one similar to that which comes with required attribute" - doesn't answer my question. Do you want a) All popups to look the same in Chrome and all popups to look the same in Firefox, but you don't care if the popups look the same between Chrome and Firefox; or b) All popups to look like the styling in [insert your favorite browser name here]? And if b, which specific browser?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

`setCustomValidity()` used to change default message in a required input field in a form.

**oninput()** event add a custom message

```
 oninput="this.setCustomValidity('Enter atleast 10 digit.')"
```

**oninvalid()** event add a custom message

```
 oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Mobile Number invalid..')"
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="phone">Mobile Number:</label>
  <input type="tel" id="mobile" name="phone" placeholder="1234567890" pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Mobile Number invalid')"
    oninput="this.setCustomValidity('Enter atleast 10 digit.')"  required><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I am already having my js to check validity so what changes do I need to make?

Comment: Iadd before you edit the question. ok let me check  now

Comment: Also can pattern attribute take a regex expression?